# How does "call __isoc99_sscanf" work

Tags: assembly, x86

I'm pretty sure the input argument on the command line is supposed to be a string, but when I get to "call __isoc99_sscanf", the eax register holds a value of 0. I don't really know how "call __isoc99_sscanf" is supposed to work, but I do know that the stack pointers are sorted like so:

.LC1
   |
   V
eax

.LC1 is "Input: %s" and eax before the "call __isoc99_sscanf" is 33 and holds a string in the memory. In any case, when does the call __isoc99_sscanf result in 1?

```
  .code32
.file   "mystery.c"
.text
.LCO:
.string "Incorrect number of command line arguments given"
.LC1:
.string "Input:%s"
.align 4
.LC2:
.string "Incorrect format for command line argument"
.LC3:
.string "Output: \"%s\"\n"
.text
 .globl main
.type   main, @function
 main:
pushl   %ebp
movl    %esp, %ebp
andl    $-16, %esp
subl    $32, %esp
cmpl    $2, 8(%ebp)
je  .L18
movl    $.LC0, (%esp)
call    puts
movl    $1, %eax
jmp .L19
.L18:
movl    12(%ebp), %eax
addl    $4, %eax
movl    (%eax), %eax
movl    %eax, (%esp)
call    strlen
movl    %eax, %edx
movl    %edx, %eax
sall    $2, %eax
addl    %edx, %eax
movl    %eax, (%esp)
call    malloc
movl    %eax, 28(%esp)
movl    $.LC1, %edx
movl    12(%ebp), %eax
addl    $4, %eax
movl    (%eax), %eax
movl    28(%esp), %ecx
movl    %ecx, 8(%esp)
movl    %edx, 4(%esp)
movl    %eax, (%esp)
call    __isoc99_sscanf
cmpl    $1, %eax
je  .L20
movl    $.LC2, (%esp)
call    puts
movl    $1, %eax
jmp .L19

 .L20:
movl    28(%esp), %eax
movl    %eax, (%esp)
call    foo
movl    $.LC3, %eax
movl    28(%esp), %edx
movl    %edx, 4(%esp)
movl    %eax, (%esp)
call    printf
movl    28(%esp), %eax
movl    %eax, (%esp)
call    free
jmp .L17
.L19:
.L17:
leave
ret
.size   main, .-main
.ident  "GCC: (GNU) 4.4.7 20120313 (Red Hat 4.4.7-4)"
.section    .note.GNU-stack,"",@progbits
```

Comment: This is 32-bit code, so EAX *before* the `call` is not meaningful.  (In the x86-64 System V ABI, `al` = number of FP args passed in XMM registers.  Which will always be 0 for scanf because you pass pointers, not values, unless the caller has undefined behaviour by passing it some FP values.)  Make sure you're looking at EAX *after* `call` by stepping over/past it, not just "when you get to" the call.

Answer (score 2):

I think this helps:

```
   man scanf:

       These  functions  return the number of input items successfully matched
   and assigned, which can be fewer than provided for, or even zero in the
   event of an early matching failure.
```

Answer (score -2):

Basically, it returns the total number of inputs you just typed into the computer. If you put two numbers in "1 4", it would set %rax to 2.

Comment: The code in the question uses a format string of `.LC1: .string "Input:%s"`  So no, with your input EAX/RAX would be 1, and the `" 4"` part of the input buffer would be left unconverted.  (And `sscanf` returns `int`, so technically it's not safe to assume it's correctly zero-extended into RAX; the upper 4 bytes of RAX could hold garbage.  But this is 32-bit code so that point is moot anyway).